# Zsh is behaving weirdly

Tags: zsh, macports, iterm

It's kind of hard to describe this issue, but here goes.

I recently updated all the ports on my Mac using

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

And now I have a display issue with zsh, as shown in this gif

[image: weird problem]

When I try to do tab completion, I get new text written over the old text. (notice the `ls Chrls ...` in the gif)

Also, sometimes the last `>` of the zsh prompt disappears.

Is anyone else facing this issue?

I'm using iTerm, zsh and zprezto.

Comment: This is usually a problem with non-printing characters in the prompt not being marked so that `zsh` can correctly determine the size of the prompt when redrawing the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I removed zprezto by doing

```
rm ~/.z*
```

and then reinstalled it following instructions from zprezto and it's back to normal again :)